# Emulator hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS) always returns false

Tags: gps

There are a couple of similar/identical questions here but none of the answers have helped me.

Basic data:
Android Studio 2.3.1 JRE: 1.8

getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS) **always** returns false

- across all emulated devices I've tested and all Android version 5.0 and up (haven't tested anything lower)
- Works fine when I connect a physical device (Samsung Galaxy Note III)
- Location services are enabled and set to high accuracy
- Google maps works fine
- When I change the Lat. Long. in extended controls google maps scrolls to the new location

It's got to be something simple and stupid but I'm at a loss.